# Поиск в глубину, вопрос из решенной задачи

Tags: c++, graph

Разбираю [задачу](http://cpp.mazurok.com/e-olimp-4000-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%B2-%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%83/) от Мазурка:

> **e-olimp 4000. Обход в глубину**
>
> Дан неориентированный невзвешенный граф, в котором выделена вершина. Вам необходимо найти количество вершин, лежащих с ней в одной компоненте связности (включая саму вершину).
>
> **Входные данные**
>
> В первой строке содержится два целых числа n и s  (1≤s≤n≤100), где n — количество вершин графа, а s — выделенная вершина. В следующих n строках записано по n чисел — матрица смежности графа, в которой цифра «0» означает отсутствие ребра между вершинами, а цифра «1» — его наличие. Гарантируется, что на главной диагонали матрицы всегда стоят нули.
>
> **Выходные данные**
>
> Выведите одно число — искомое количество вершин.
>
> **Пример**
>
> ```
> Входные данные    Выходные данные
> 5 1
> 0 1 1 0 0
> 1 0 1 0 0
> 1 1 0 0 0         3
> 0 0 0 0 1
> 0 0 0 1 0
> ```

Я вот до 24-ой строки понимаю, объясните пожалуйста, что происходит после неё:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>

int main()
{
    int n;
    int s;
    std::cin >> n >> s;
    s--;
    int matrix[n][n];
    stack<int> st;
    int counter = 1;

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            std::cin >> matrix[i][j];
    }
    for(int j = 0;j < n; j++)
        if(matrix[s][j] == 1) st.push(j);

    matrix[s][s] = 1;            // <<<=== Вот отсюда становится непонятно
    while(!st.empty())
    {
        int a = st.top();
        st.pop();
        if(matrix[a][a]!=1)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < n; j++)
                if(matrix[a][j] == 1) st.push(j);

            counter++;
            matrix[a][a] = 1;
        }
    }

    std::cout << counter << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сначала стоит напомнить, что компонента связности — это набор вершин, которые достижимы друг из друга. То есть надо посчитать количество вершин, до которых можно дойти из вершины *s* по рёбрам.

Также напомню для себя, то цикл в строках 21-23 запихивает в стек вершины, непосредственно соединённые с *s*.

Дальше, в строке 24 (`matrix[s][s] = 1`), производится нарушение условия входных данных: *Гарантируется, что на главной диагонали матрицы всегда стоят нули*. То есть по умолчанию там нули, и записью единиц программа возводит для себя какие-то флаги. Какие именно — становится понятно в строках 30 (`if(matrix[a][a] != 1)`) и 37 (`matrix[a][a] = 1`): подобным образом алгоритм помечает уже учтённые вершины, чтобы не ходить по ним рекурсивно кругами.

Ну а в целом всё более-менее прямолинейно: берём очередной элемент из стека (изначально там непосредственные соседи вершины *s*, но позднее он будет пополняться), смотрим, не посещали ли её ранее. Если нет — добавляем её непосредственных соседей в стек, увеличиваем счётчик посещённых вершин на единицу и помечаем вершину как посещённую. Если стек не пуст (то есть мы хоть кого-то добавили, либо не успели разобрать уже добавленных), то возвращаемся в начало цикла, берём очередной элемент из стека и т. д.

Comment: а строка 24 не показывается типо берет вершину саму себя как в условии?

Comment: @Estet, в этой строке алгоритм соединяет вершину ребром саму с собой. Так как подобная ситуация во входных данных исключена, алгоритм пользуется подобной невозможностью в своих внутренних целях. Кстати, эта строка по смыслу полностью аналогична `matrix[s][s]`, только здесь мы отмечаем как посещённую не *очередную*, а *начальную* вершину.

Comment: А s у нас же 0 в данный момент, т.к s--, нулевая вершина связывается самой с собой? Или просто так определяем?

Comment: @Estet, по условию *s ≥ 1*. Индексация же массивов начинается не с единицы , а с нуля. Поэтому мы и выполняем сдвиг порядкового номера стартового элемента (`s--`).

Answer (score 3):

Суть алгоритма: рекурсивно обходить все вершины, связные с данной, пока не переберем все вершины, до которых можно добраться. Для этого используется вспомогательный стек, в который заталкиваются еще не испробованные вершины.

```
  matrix[s][s] = 1;            // <<<=== Вот отсюда становится непонятно
```

Вершина помечается, чтобы 2 раза не обрабатывать.

```
if(matrix[a][a]!=1) // необработанная вершина 
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < n; j++) // все ее смежные
                if(matrix[a][j] == 1) st.push(j);//заталкиваются в стек

            counter++;// и ее сосчитали
            matrix[a][a] = 1;
        }
```